# mdadm RAID6, recover 2 disk failure during reshape

Tags: linux, mdadm, raid6

I was reshaping my array from 10 disks to 11 to a degraded state (drive I want to add already has data on it, but nowhere to put it). 2 drives disconnected while it was running (power issue).

Is it still possible to recovery this array?

After power cycling them I was unable to add them to the array again:

```
mdadm: /dev/md0 has failed so using --add cannot work and might destroy
mdadm: data on /dev/sdX1.  You should stop the array and re-assemble it.
```

Since rebooting, I've tried:

--assemble, fails due to "faulty" disks

--assemble --force, fails:

```
md: sdl1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md: sdk1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md/raid:md0: not enough operational devices (3/11 failed)
md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.`
```

I've been reading the [RAID Recovery](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery) article, but so far not been successful.

`mdadm --create --chunk=64 --size=1953512448 --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=11 /dev/md0 /dev/sd{f,h,e,g,m,i,k,l,n,d}1 missing`, fails:

```
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is smaller than given size. 1953512256K < 1953512448K + metadata
```

for all drives. My argument to --size is "Used Dev Size / 2" from mdadm --examine /dev/sdf1. I've downgraded mdadm to each version down to v3.1.2 (when default metadata was changed to 1.2, I know I never specified it manually).

Removing --size, I can create the array, but not mount:

```
XFS (md0): Mounting V4 Filesystem
XFS (md0): Log inconsistent (didn't find previous header)
XFS (md0): failed to find log head
XFS (md0): log mount/recovery failed: error -5
XFS (md0): log mount failed
```

### Info

My `mdadm --detail` before reshape:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 15628099584 (14904.12 GiB 16003.17 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953512448 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 10
  Total Devices : 10
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 14:16:09 2015
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 10
Working Devices : 10
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : ubuntu:0
           UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
         Events : 6037532

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       81        0      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       9       8      177        1      active sync   /dev/sdl1
      12       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
       3       8       97        3      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       4       8      145        4      active sync   /dev/sdj1
       6       8      193        5      active sync   /dev/sdm1
       7       8      113        6      active sync   /dev/sdh1
       8       8      129        7      active sync   /dev/sdi1
      10       8      161        8      active sync   /dev/sdk1
      11       8       49        9      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

And `mdadm --examine` after failure and reboot with all disks visible again:

Device paths have changed as there was a hotswap disk added before reshape started

```
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 329fc32d:e9cf2ff4:3aa6c9a0:500aa445

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : 904d0c9c - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : A.AAA...AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e59303ea:e613013e:ef8af657:1fc6ccab

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : b3b3f659 - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : A.AAA...AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6aa0f9d8:e7b0cc66:d2f2a600:ef305279

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3148373376 (3002.52 GiB 3223.93 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : 3beac20c - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4b1d87a9:16027400:df71810f:3ce53c50

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : 91a563ea - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : A.AAA...AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdh1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 5860268032 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 27c8fefa:8b2b74a2:9a456d34:d1a60c20

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:29:09 2015
       Checksum : ee4ae103 - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA..AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdi1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bebc3764:9e582fe8:01de9766:2d8c452b

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:29:09 2015
       Checksum : 6632686d - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAA..AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 5860268032 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 986d9f31:3a74b90d:7800779e:31607539

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3148373376 (3002.52 GiB 3223.93 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:24:09 2015
       Checksum : de0a23b - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdl1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 5860268032 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a5f4ac69:f6bbac94:60c1b790:db2c223e

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:28:58 2015
       Checksum : c9909fb9 - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : AAAAAA.AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdm1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 938d9190:582eecf8:b9157fce:38705df2

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : d2462ecd - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : A.AAA...AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)


/dev/sdn1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 70485ad1:0f5f2362:e8f5489a:577ac908
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 27 19:20:36 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 11

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 17581612032 (16767.13 GiB 18003.57 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 289f68f6:f43d8a40:2203e21c:e6cff371

Internal Bitmap : 2 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 3196923264 (3048.82 GiB 3273.65 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (10->11)

    Update Time : Wed Jun 17 19:46:34 2015
       Checksum : 4db49d1a - correct
         Events : 6039833

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 8
   Array State : A.AAA...AA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the good news is that all ten drives have matching Event counts at 6039833.

I think the key to success is resolving why you are seeing...

```
md: sdl1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md: sdk1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
```

This is an interesting case and certainly it will take some study to figure out a solution. If you would like some help contact me via the web link in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't tell here whole story, I suspect that power failure was during raid resync, if so then --auto-assemble won't work. It's time to recover from backup or use professional help.

Comment: This is the whole story. It was being reshaped into a degraded state (10/11 drives), then 2 drives disconnected leaving it with 8/11.
Looking at md0 in a hex editor, it seems alright. I can see filenames and data that I recognise (also the XFS header starts in the correct place). Currently running xfs_repair -n to try and find a secondary superblock.. but it's going to take a few days since it's a 15TB filesystem.